# ping timeout command -W not working for Android

Tags: android, ping

In my Android application, I have used the ping command with appropriate option mentioned in below link:
http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_ping.htm

All other options are working except -W which is timeout.

I am using this command to ping with 5sec time out: ping 131.107.8.1 -W 5
I believe this should give "Request timed out" after 5sec. I also tested it with "Test Ping" application but it failed there as well.

Where as in my windows machine, I am using this command for same IP: ping 131.107.8.1 -w 7000
And it is properly giving "Request timed out" after 7000msec.

Any pointer where am I missing the concept?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure on Android's implementation of Ping, but on Linux the flags `ping -w` and `ping -W` have very different operations.

In this case, you're using `ping -W`, which waits for a timeout to happen across the network. According to the man page:

> -W timeout
>                Time to wait for a response, in seconds. The option affects only
>                timeout in absense of any responses, otherwise  ping  waits  for
>                two RTTs.

I believe what you're attempting to do is set a deadline for the Ping command, e.g. `ping -w` as described by the man page again:

> -w deadline
>                Specify  a  timeout, in seconds, before ping exits regardless of
>                how many packets have been sent or received. In this  case  ping
>                does  not  stop after count packet are sent, it waits either for
>                deadline expire or until count probes are answered or  for  some
>                error notification from network.

Answer (score 0):

> Ping timeouts only start after the IP address has been determined. If
>   your workstation is offline, then ping cannot determine the IP address
>   and so appears to wait approximately a default 20 secs before
>   returning false.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/739873/156789